What is wrong with my dual router topology?
ISP-provided cable modem/router is severely crippled, so I have been using another router with more functionalities for months.
Both are near each other, but I need to move them apart, mostly in order to have two Wi-Fi access points for better coverage.
In the figure, the original (working) topology and the new one.
For some reason, with the new topology wired devices have problems to access most web addresses (for some reason, Google ones do work).
What's wrong? How should it be?




What moving them apart has to do with changing from the correct LAN to WAN connection to a LAN to LAN?

"How should it be?" - The conventional setup would have the DHCP service on the Humax (ISP) unit instead of the downstream Asus unit.

I wonder if the issue could be that the RT-AC86U is handing out a default gateway of 192.168.1.1 rather then 192.168.1.254 - If that is the case then clients will be able to see each other but not find a path out the Internet.

Most routers require you to use the WAN port. You can still use the router with DHCP disabled on the modem just assign a static intranet IP address manually

@ChanganAuto: Roaming. If you keep using the WAN port, you don't really get a large network with better coverage, you get two networks each with its original poor coverage.

Davidgo's answer has the most chance of being correct with the information given. I think that your new setup is better (one LAN, no NAT behind NAT). The easiest fix is probably going to be turning DHCP on on the ISP router and off on your own router. Otherwise you will have to change your own router to either give out 192.168.1.254 as default gateway or add a route for 0.0.0.0 -> 192.168.1.254.

@ChanganAuto
Whith the original topology, clients connected to the Humax would get 192.168.0.xxx address and would not reach devices connected to the Asus (192.168.1.xxx)

@sawdust
That's exactly the problem: the (crippled by ISP) Humax doesn't even offer address reservation and I need that.

@davidgo
Oh my bad!
Left gateway address empty, so Asus thought itself was the gateway.
Thanks!
